# Jar not found in Maven Repository

Tags: java, maven, jar, repository

I am trying to add a dependency in my project(i am using maven) however the jar i want to add it seems like it does not exist in the maven central repository.The jar i want to add is Neko HTML jar version 1.9.22.When i am searching for the jar through the add dependency dialog from netbeans the jar is not displayed,however the jar seems to exist on the maven central repository->https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml/1.9.22(Search through google)

Then result i get from the add dependency dialog is this ->
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wo1ix3lefwxy91a/DepDialog.JPG?dl=0

I did not manage to find a solution,so i would appreciate it if someone could help me figure this out.

Comment: ->https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml/1.9.22 (Search through google)

Comment: Does it work when you edit the pom.xml?

Comment: You mean like editing the pom.xml file manually?
(Manually like writing groupId,artifact,version myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/nekohtml/nekohtml/1.9.22/

```
<groupId>net.sourcefourge.nekohtml</groupId>
<artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
<version>1.19.22</version>
```

Comment: Thank you, foryour answer the url help me to type better keyword in the add dependency dialog of netbeans.